# Receive anonymous users' input by web upload form or email. Any online service for that?

Tags: database, image-hosting, user-generated-content

Are you aware of any online service or online "platform" allowing users, not previously registered, to upload pairs of picture+comment to a database?

It would be a collaborative database of picture+comment pairs.

I'm not going wiki or googlegroup, picasa or such because I'd like the user to have the least to do to participate, that is e.g.: take a picture with his phone and email it to an email to an email address. Or go to a web page with an upload form, type in a description, hit OK and that's it.

And the goal is also that it be as hassle-less to put up as possible. Yeah I know, it can't programme itself to my requirements :) by I'm suspecting there's a tool or tool combination going a decent way through my needs.

Thanks for any info/advice! SJA

(NB the final goal is a kind of crowd-sourced census of specific urban items. If you have comment about the potential for spam-overload of my idea, other than "you're doomed", you're welcome!)

Answer (score 3):

You can sign up for a Flickr Pro account (not free otherwise you can only see the last 200 pictures) and tell people the email address that they've set up for you on this page: http://www.flickr.com/account/uploadbyemail/

> You can use the subject line to give
>   your photo or video a title and the
>   body to add a description.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Posterous](http://posterous.com/) and set up a Group, which does exactly what you describe. A group gives you a `yourgroup@posterous.com` address, and anyone can email photos to that address for it to appear on the group page.

For example, in [this blog post](http://blog.posterous.com/an-app-to-end-it-posterous-events-at-graduati) they create a collaborative photo album for a graduation ceremony.

To get started, sign up on their homepage with your email address, username, and password, then choose the 'group' box in the popup you see on the next page:

[image]

You can then choose to make the group private (invite only) or public (anyone can post):

[image]